# VBA Runtime error 1004 on Cells(..).Formula

Tags: vba, excel

I can't make this simple command work:

```
Cells(l, 7).Formula = "=" & var1 & " * " & var2 & " * " & var3 & " / 252"
```

I can paste the inspected formula string value in Excel and it works as expected.

Cells(l,7) is a proper reference, as I can inspect its value.

Inspected formula on debug:
"=86710597,9409 * 0,02 * 0,35 / 252"

Comment: what values have your var1...var3 ??

Comment: @KazJaw I added that to the post

Comment: Is the dangling right-paren a typo?

Comment: Try to change commas to dots.

Comment: @rontornambe it is a typo, sorry

Comment: I am not an Excel expert, but the "=" & seems redundant. Have you tried removing it?

Comment: @Voitcus Ya that was it. Do I always have to represent decimal numbers on vba with "." ? thanks

Comment: Yes. And you should always use original (ie. English) function names. Glad it helped.

Comment: I posted it as an answer so maybe in future someone can find the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is when a variable is represented as string it will have the system's decimal point. In your case it is a comma so you need to convert it to dot, for example using [`replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) function.

Comment: or use `.FormulaLocal` to use the language settings of the user